# How would I add credentials to an url? I am getting the error HTTP failed unauthorized

Tags: php, caldav

I have a CalDav and it has the ability to export .ics files.

I want to do this remotely, but it tells me

> Failed to open stream HTTP request failed Unauthorized.

I found out we're using Digest authentication instead of basic. Does this matter a whole lot in the way to access to url?

Here is the code I am using.

```
$url = 'http://localhost/projects/baikal/html/dav.php/calendars/user/calendar-1/?export';

$file = 'calendar.ics';

$credentials = "username:password";

$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'header' => 'Authorization: Basic ' . base64_encode($credentials)
    )
));

copy($url, $file, $context);
```

EDIT: When manually accessing the URL and filling in the credentials it works without any issues.

Comment: If you visit the URL manually and enter the same credentials does it work? We have no idea if the error is because the credentials are simply wrong, or something else.

Comment: @ADyson Yes if I manually do that it works without any issues. Sorry I did not think it was necessary to include that.

Comment: You'd be surprised how often we get questions where people haven't done a basic test beforehand :-)

Comment: I can imagine people just jumping on the "It doesn't work" bandwagon.